# please explain the difference between these two queries

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Sub Query 1:**

```
select employee_id,last_name,salary
from employees
where salary > (select round(avg(salary),0)
                from employees
               )
order by salary
```

**Sub Query 2:**

```
select employee_id,last_name,salary
from employees
where salary > all (select round(avg(salary),0)
                    from employees
                   )
order by salary
```

Comment: Learn how to ask question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any difference off-hand.  The subquery returns exactly one row -- the average salary.  The presence or absence of the `all` keyword doesn't matter for a scalar subquery.  If `salary` is only `NULL`, then both queries return no rows.